# Center-align horizontally UI items on the same row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I'm attempting to create my first Android app and I'd like to center horizontally align two elements on the same row so that they appear on top of each other.

I've tried setting the layout_row to the same value and gravity to center however that shows the ChartView and not the (serviceScore) TextView. If I remove the ChartView, the (serviceScore) TextView displays as expected however I want to display them both. What am I missing? Also, any ideas why the chart cuts off at the bottom?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
        app:boxedEdges="all"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:rowCount="8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:columnCount="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:textSize="9dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_row="1"/>
            <microcharts.droid.ChartView
                android:id="@+id/chartView"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:gravity="center" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:text="test"
                android:id="@+id/serviceScore"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="50dp"/>
        </GridLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

UI:

[image]

Comment: What actually happens with your code ?

Comment: @Niceumang Sorry, what do you mean? The above code displays a slightly cropped chartView but doesn't display serviceScore. I want them both displayed - center aligned on the same row.

Comment: What's up with all the layouts? Just one vertical LinearLayout, your three items in there, centered horizontally -> done. Or if they need to be over each other, use a ContraintLayout.

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center" of your framelayout

Answer (score 1):

use android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" as,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
        tools:deviceIds="wear">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
            android:boxedEdges="all"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
            <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:rowCount="8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:columnCount="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:textSize="9dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_row="1"/>
                <microcharts.droid.ChartView
                    android:id="@+id/chartView"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:gravity="center" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:id="@+id/serviceScore"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="50dp"/>
            </GridLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```